# Is it possible to use value from application.properties in an annotation in a spring-boot application?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a custom annotation `@SynapseActivity` like below

```
@SynapseActivity(taskQueue = "ens", startToCloseTimeoutMs = 1000)
public interface FeatureFlagActivity {
...
}
```

Is it possible to read the value of `taskQueue` from `application.properties` for some cases?

I tried to do the below but it is not working.

```
@SynapseActivity(taskQueue = "${spring.application.name}", startToCloseTimeoutMs = 1000)
public interface FeatureFlagActivity {
...
}
```

- spring-boot = 3.0.9

Comment: In Spring annotations you sometimes can use Spring's Expression Language (SpEL), but for other libraries/annotations the answer is likely not.

Comment: As it's a custom annotation, it's up to the code that's processing the value of `taskQueue` to decide what syntax the value can have and how it should be processed. Whose code processes the value of `taskQueue`?

Comment: My code processes the value of `taskQueue`.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson: Injecting `Envrionment` or `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` and trying to resolve, won't that work supposingly code that processes this annotation has the capability ?

Comment: @tuk then you can resolve the properties in that code. I'd use an `EmbeddedValueResolver` to do so which you can have injected by implementing `EmbeddedValueResolverAware`. This is what Spring Framework's `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` does for example.